# float: left, keep other element text-align: center

Tags: css, css-float, vertical-alignment, text-alignment

A while ago I asked a question about [how to align some content on the left, some content in the middle, but keep them vertically aligned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27830732/aligning-elements-with-different-horizontal-position-along-vertical-axis-withou).

Through the answers I received there and some further searching, I've come up with two almost perfect solutions. But I'd like to know if there is some way to combine them into a solution which fulfills all my requirements.

Those requirements are:

- no hard-coding of width or height
- some content aligned left, some content aligned center
- left-aligned and center-aligned content vertically-aligned with each other
- both left- and center-aligned content obey padding in parent (or parent of parent)
- no unnecessary scrolling
- center-aligned content must not be allowed to overlap with left-aligned content (not satisfied by solution #1)
- center-aligned content must be TRULY centered (not satisfied by solution #2)
- compatible with IE 8
- EDIT: if centered content is wide, it must use up all the available space (i.e. until it bumps up against the left-aligned content)

Of these requirements, the overlapping content is the one I'm most willing to put up with, since it will only happen if the window is made much smaller.

Solution #1 - uses `position: absolute; left: 0`, ✓ truly centered, ✗ no overlaps

```css
.nav-btn-set-left {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    border: 1px solid green;
}

.title-bar {
    padding: 5px 10px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: lightblue;
    font-size: 50px;
}

.nav-btn-set-parent {
    border: 1px solid orange;
    position: relative;
}

.nav-btn {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="title-bar">
    <div class="nav-btn-set-parent">
        <div class="nav-btn-set-left">
            <input type="button" value="Button1" class="nav-btn"/>
            <input type="button" value="Button2" class="nav-btn"/>
        </div>
        Heading
    </div>
</div>
```

Solution #2 - uses `float: left;`, ✗ truly centered, ✓ no overlaps

```css
.nav-btn-set-left {
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    border: 1px solid green;
}

.title-bar {
    padding: 5px 10px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: lightblue;
    font-size: 50px;
}

.nav-btn-set-parent {
    border: 1px solid orange;
    position: relative;
}

.nav-btn {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="title-bar">
    <div class="nav-btn-set-parent">
        <div class="nav-btn-set-left">
            <input type="button" value="Button1" class="nav-btn"/>
            <input type="button" value="Button2" class="nav-btn"/>
        </div>
        Heading
    </div>
</div>
```

Can anyone find a way to unify these two approaches to satisfy all the requirements? Or is it impossible without newer CSS? If you have a solution with newer CSS like flex-box that won't work with older browsers, that's still worth posting.

Comment: Is it OK to adjust the markup?

Comment: Yep, adjusting the markup is fine. CSS and HTML always intertwined to a degree anyway.

Answer (score 2):

If it's OK to adjust the markup slightly read on.

http://jsfiddle.net/2gddfxbo/

```css
.nav-btn-set-parent {
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}
.table-cell {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: 1px solid red;
    padding: 20px 0;
}
.heading-cell {
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="title-bar">
    <div class="nav-btn-set-parent">
        <div class="table-cell nav-btn-set-left">
            <input type="button" value="Button1" class="nav-btn"/>
            <input type="button" value="Button2" class="nav-btn"/>
        </div>
        <div class="table-cell heading-cell">Heading</div>
        <div class="table-cell"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also add this if necessary:

```
.heading-cell {
    text-align: center;
    width: 50%; /*adjustable*/
}
```

Comment: I like where you went with it, but there's a slight problem with it, in that the heading text will wrap once it overflows the center table cell, even though there's a lot of the div with empty space. Change "Heading" to something much longer to see what I mean. I guess I should add that as a requirement.

Comment: @ChrisMiddleton have you seen the updated part at the bottom of the answer, quick demo - http://jsfiddle.net/2gddfxbo/1/ other than that, it is gonna be really difficult with pure css, looks like you want the left box to be out of the content flow, and put it back if necessary, will media queries help? but still you'll have to define a breakpoint.